# SQL to filter out records from a table if a column value is not found after grouping or partitioning

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table, that has 3 columns AccountNumber Memberid Status, an accountnumber will have multiple memberids associated with it and with status either "A" Active  or "C" Closed, my output should be only those Accountnumbers where there is atleast 1 active member, if there is not even one active member then i do not want that Accountnumber in my output, please keep in mind, if an accountnumber has multiple closed and atleast 1 active i want all those records in my output. DBMS is DB2 but i can tweak around.

Comment: please keep in mind that it is not free code writing community

Comment: i wasnt expecting a free code, just some ideas, stop being cheap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the account numbers (which seems to be what you want) with `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select accountnumber
from table t
group by accountnumber
having sum(case when status = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `having` clause simply counts up the number of rows in the group where the condition is true.  The `> 0` says that there is at least one active member.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename]
WHERE [AccountNumber] IN (
    SELECT [AccountNumber] FROM [tablename]
    WHERE [status] = 'c'
)
```